# mysql time for select not same as real lines

Tags: mysql, select, explain

I met a unexpect result in my mysql server.

the lines more , the query time less??

I have one table and for the total rows for each filter:

```
select count(*) from tcr where eid=648;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    11336 |
select count(*) from tcr  where eid=997;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1262307 |
```

but the query time is oppisite to the total lines for each filter:

```
select * from tcr where eid=648 order by start_time desc limit 0,10;
[data display]
10 rows in set (16.92 sec)

select * from tcr  where eid=997 order by start_time desc limit 0,10;
[data display]
10 rows in set (0.21 sec)
```

"reset query cache" has been execute before every query sql.
the index of table tcr is

```
KEY `cridx_eid` (`eid`),
KEY `cridx_start_time` (`start_time`)
```

BTW:attach the explain result: this is very strange, but it looks more like the reuslt we take.(the eid=997 has less lines than eid=648

```
explain select * from talk_call_record where eid=648 order by start_time desc limit 0,10;
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys | key              | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
 +----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | talk_call_record | index | cridx_eid     | cridx_start_time | 5       | NULL | 3672 | Using where |

```
explain select * from talk_call_record where eid=997 order by start_time desc limit 0,10;
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+

| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys | key              | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | talk_call_record | index | cridx_eid     | cridx_start_time | 5       | NULL |   32 | Using where |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must have a very large table.

MySQL is using the index on `start_time` for the queries.  What is happening is that it is "walking" through the table, one row at a time.  It happens to find `eid=997` much more quickly than it finds `eid=648`.  It only has to find 10 records, so the engine stops when it gets to the 10th one.

What can you do?  The optimal index for the query is a composite index on `(eid, start_time)`.  This will go directly to the values that you want.